# Find and replace in file from values in master file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, scripting

I want to replace values in a file with look up values in another master file

I am currently using the below command to do that

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub(i, array[i]) }1' map.txt test1.txt
```

> cat map.txt
>
> NOT NULL
>
> cat test.txt
>
> CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
>
> **Result:**
>
> **CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NULL NULL**

**It works fine for single word to be replaced.**

**But when i give multiple words inside quotes say**

> cat map.txt
>
> 'NOT NULL' 'NULL'

**Expected output:**

**CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NULL**

It's not working if i have to replace multiple words combined.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the have to be quoted? And are the replacement sets in map.txt all equal? Meaning that there are two words working as an index for one word.

Comment: [edit] your question to use the `{}` button to properly format your input and output so we have something we can copy/paste to test against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you can live without quoting the words and map.txt file looks the same for all replacements you can do something like:

```
aawk 'FNR==NR{ array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub(i, array[i]) }1' FS=":" map.txt FS=" " test.txt
```

cat test.txt

```
CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
```

cat map.txt

```
NOT NULL : NULL
```

Output:

```
CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NULL
```

Another one:

cat test.txt

```
CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
```

cat map.txt

```
SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT : NULL
```

Output:

```
CHARACTER  NULL NULL
```

The Adjustment you have to make is to the map file by separating the two fields (target for replacement, replacement) by : (or anything else, just change it in the script). If you do that it keeps the script at a low complexity but working for now matter how many words you want to replace.

Comment: This is not giving me the desired output.
What it does is replaces 'NOT' with 'NULL' .
What i need is to replace 'NOT NULL' with 'NULL'

Comment: Any other suggestions?
I've tried using quotes too, its not working.

Comment: Mhhh, that is strange. So if use the test.txt and the map.txt as posted it is replacing NOT NULL with NULL. But is not working with quotes.

Comment: It's not replacing NOT NULL with NULL when i did what you suggested or either using quotes.
All i need is to replace multiple words together which is not working currently.

Comment: Mhh, so the construct { array[$1 FS $2]=$3; next } catches NOT NULL as a key for the value NOT. So when it loops over the array it sees the Key NOT NULL in test.txt and gsubs it with the Value which is NULL. Or I'am missing something here........*scratch my head*

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you tell me what your OS and awk version are?

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.7
Linux.

Comment: Ok, so I'am not that much into differences between versions but since the answer from kapu is also working for me I guess it has something to do with the version. I have 4.0.1.

Comment: Answer from kapu is working for you for different inputs as well ?
Then maybe its down to version only i guess.

Comment: Not with different input. But mine is still working for example if I try to substitute SET LATIN with FOO then my map file would look like SET LATIN FOO

Comment: Try replacing CHARACTER SET LATIN with foo.
It does not work :)

Comment: Of course that does no work. Thats why I asked below your question if the format of replacing is always the same. If you want to replace three words or two words that is a difference. So the script has to be changed to handle that.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I missed that.
It's not fixed actually.It will vary.It can go till 5-6 max.

Comment: So I will change my answer according to that.

Comment: Thank you so much:)

Comment: Done. Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: This will fail due to partial matches, regexp metacharacters, backreference metacharacters, strings being constructed by the substitution and THEN matching the regexp, etc. so YMMV...